# Trying to export results to CSV file in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I tried few ways to do this with export-csv and Out-File, but both times it seems it outputs my script rather then result. It seems the error is this part
$WhoAreYou{} but not sure how to fix it...

Here is the full code

```
$IP = Get-NetIPAddress | Where-Object {$_.IPAddress -like "172*"} | Select IPAddress
$hostname = $env:COMPUTERNAME

$WhoAreYou = {

IP = $IP
Hostname = $hostname

}

$whoareyou | Export-Csv "\\MyComputer\c$\WhoAreYouDevice\ThisIs.csv" -Force
```

I feel like I am close but just can't get it...

Comment: `$WhoAreYou = [PSCustomObject]@{ ... }`

Comment: `Select IPAddress` --> `Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress`

Answer (score 0):

The comment posted resolved my issue.
In the meantime I also managed to find a similar way to do this:

```
$IP = Get-NetIPAddress | Where-Object {$_.IPAddress -like "172*"} | Select IPAddress

New-Object PSObject -Property @{

IPAddress = $IP
Hostname = $env:COMPUTERNAME

} | Export-Csv "\\MyPC\c$\WhoAreYouDevice\ThisIs.csv" -Force
```

Comment: You're not using your `$hostname` variable.

Comment: Ah, yes, well spotted. I have made the edit.

Comment: You can also add the `-notypeinformation` parameter to your export cmdlet. Gets rid of the type information that's exported to the csv